# starting a new activity within a frame window

Tags: android

I have two frames define likes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:orientation="vertical"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
android:layout_height="match_parent">     

<fragment class="com.test.act"         
    android:id="@+id/list"             
    android:layout_weight="1"             
    android:layout_width="match_parent"             
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />      
<fragment android:name="com.test.nact"             
    android:id="@+id/viewer"             
    android:layout_weight="1"             
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

In the second frame based on user input (clicking a button) I want to lauch a new activity which was coded previously by somebody else.  So in the onCreateView function I create a new intent and start it like this:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent( view.getContext(), PictureActivity.class );
startActivityForResult( newIntent, ACTION_REQUEST_PIC );
```

However what happens is that PictureActivity gets launched and takes over the entire screen also overwriting the com.test.act fragment part of the display.  I want the PictureActivity to get display only in the com.act.nact part of the display.  How can Ido that?